# Typescript error in the Solana chain. (Solana transaction in testnet)

Tags: typescript, solana

I am trying to make Solana NFT transaction code with Typescript & react.

When run this code in only Typescript, It works normally.

But in react, error occurs.

```
import { Keypair ,Connection, Transaction, sendAndConfirmTransaction, PublicKey} from "@solana/web3.js";
import Wallet from "@project-serum/sol-wallet-adapter";
import { Token, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID} from"@solana/spl-token"
const Solana = new Connection("https://api.testnet.solana.com/","confirmed")
import { EventEmitter} from eventemitter3
interface WalletAdapter extends EventEmitter {
    publicKey: PublicKey | null;
    signTransaction: (transaction: Transaction) => Promise<Transaction>;
    connect: () => any;
    disconnect: () => any;}
const wallet: WalletAdapter = new Wallet("https://www.sollet.io", "https://api.testnet.solana.com/");
const letsNftTrans = async () => {
    const DEMO_FROM_SECRET_KEY = new Uint8Array([
        223, 119, 171,   5, 237, 138,  42, 140, 176, 163,  74,
        107,  25, 143,  90,  97, 250, 158, 203, 102, 238,  19,
        77, 228, 211, 238, 147, 149,  40,  50, 211, 155,  51,
        207,  14,  53,  86, 230, 164,  27,  14, 202,  78, 181,
        185, 250,  16,  52, 134, 242,  96,  16,  12,  67,   2,
        178, 106, 241, 156, 212,  11, 150, 114,  72]);
    const DEMO_Keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(DEMO_FROM_SECRET_KEY)
    let mint;
    let myToken;
    let toTokenAccount;
    mint = await Token.createMint(Solana, DEMO_Keypair, DEMO_Keypair.publicKey, null, 9, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID)
    myToken = await mint.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(DEMO_Keypair.publicKey)
    setTimeout(async function () {
    mint = await Token.createMint(Solana, DEMO_Keypair, DEMO_Keypair.publicKey, null, 9, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID)
    console.log('mint public address: ' + mint.publicKey.toBase58());
    myToken = await mint.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(DEMO_Keypair.publicKey)
    toTokenAccount =  await mint.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(wallet?.publicKey!)
    mint.mintTo(myToken.address, DEMO_Keypair.publicKey,[], 1000000000);
    await mint.setAuthority(mint.publicKey, null, "MintTokens", DEMO_Keypair.publicKey, [])
    const mintTransaction = new Transaction().add(Token.createTransferInstruction(
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        myToken.address,
        toTokenAccount.address,
        DEMO_Keypair.publicKey,
        [],
        1000000000
        )
    )
    const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    Solana,
    mintTransaction,
    [DEMO_Keypair],
    {commitment:"confirmed"}
    )
    console.log('SIGNATURE', signature)
    }, 20000)}
```

This is where the error occurs.

```
console.log('token public address : '+ myToken.address.toBase58());
toTokenAccount =  await mint.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(wallet?.publicKey!)
console.log('ToTokenAccount :'+toTokenAccount)
```

This is an error message output from the Chrome console window.

browser js:47 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'digest')

Also, it works differently in local and network environments.
Local: http://localhost:port => No Error.
On Your Network:  http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:port // Error.

Hw can I solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like there's some context missing here.  The error is around a `wallet` variable which has not been declared elsewhere.  Perhaps the wallet isn't available on testnet, but has enough funds on your local network.

Comment: Thanks, I took care of the missing parts. :D